# Return the number of times that the string appears using loops

Tags: python

Return the number of times that the string `"hi"` appears anywhere in the given string.

```
count_hi('abc hi ho') # → 1

count_hi('ABChi hi') # → 2

count_hi('hihi') # → 2
```

I have this solution with me;

```
def count_hi(str):
    return str.count("hi")
```

But I am looking for a solution using a given hint: Use the `for i in range(len(str)-1):` loop to look at each index in the string, except the last. For each `i`, extract the string starting at `i` and up to but not including `i+2`. Check if that string is `"hi"`, and count how many times that happens.

I even tried this solution, but doesn't pass all the test cases:

```
def count_hi(str):
    count = 0
    for char in str:
        if char == 'hi':
           count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Do you want "hire" count, since it contains "hi"?

Comment: No, I am practicing form this website, http://codingbat.com/prob/p167246

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one version:

```
def count_hi(s):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        count += s[i]=='h' and s[i+1]=='i'
    return count
```

Here is another:

```
def count_hi2(s):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        count += s[i:i+2] == 'hi'
    return count
```

#### Discussion

Consider this code fragment:

```
for char in str:
    if char == 'hi':
```

This loops through the individual characters in the string `str`.  Thus, in this loop, `char` is always one single character.  Consequently, it will never be equal to two characters.

Also, it best practice to use a different name for strings: `str` is a builtin.  Python will let you freely overwrite builtins but a consequence is that you will lose easy access them.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string:

```
string = 'hire test foo hi bar high'
split_string = [[item]+['hi'] for item in string.split('hi') if item != ""]
split_string = sum(split_string, [])
```

And use a `for` loop to count the matching strings:

```
string_count = 0
for item in range(len(split_string)):
    if split_string[item] == 'hi':
        string_count += 1
```

**Or**, you can skip the `for` loop and directly count the list:

```
split_string.count('hi') # returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_hi(str):
  len_w = len(str)
  txt = str.replace("hi", "")
  len_wo = len(txt)
  return (len_w- len_wo)/2
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please always try to add some explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_hi(str1):

#use the replace method to replace all spaces
  str1 = list(str1.replace(' ',''))
  print(str1)
        
  '''define a counter variable that increments by one everytime the if cond 
  is met'''

  count = 0
    
  for i in range(len(str1)-1):
    if str1[i] == "h" and str1[i+1] == "i":
      count += 1
  return count
```

Comment: You should avoid using Python's reserved keywords like `str` in your code. Plus, code only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: Why are you removed the spaces? I'm pretty in the question as asked, `count_hi("h i")` should return 0.

Comment: Plus, this code looks a lot like the accepted answer, can you explain what you are adding to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_hi(str):
  my_list = []
  for each in range(len(str) - 1):
    if str[each] == "h":
      next_item = str[each + 1]
      my_list.append(str[each] + next_item)

  total = my_list.count("hi")
  return total
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/3216427) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int countHi(String str) {
  int count = 0;
  for( int i = 0 ; i < str.length()-1 ; i++){
  if ( str.substring(i , i+2).equals("hi"))
  count = count + 1;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: The question was for python, this is for a different language.